# Получить ключ по значению

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть словарь:

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

и есть строка:

```
stroka = 'a3a2c'
```

Если элемент строки есть среди значений словаря, необходимо вывести соответствующий значению ключ. Если среди ключей - то вывести значение по ключу значение. Вывести необходимо в две строки, значения отдельно от ключей.

Т.е. для строки `'a3a2c'` ожидаемый вывод `'113'` и `'cb'`

Как вывести значения по ключу, я разобрался:

```
for i in stroka:
    if i in d.keys():
        print(d[i], end='')
```

А вот вывести ключ по значению у меня не получается:

```
for j in stroka:
    if j in d.values():
        print(?????, end='')
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Как то так:

```
d = {
    1: '1',
    '2': 2,
    3: '3',
}


def get_key(d, value):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v == value:
            return k

print(get_key(d, '1'))
print(get_key(d, 2))
print(get_key(d, 42))
```

Консоль:

```
1
2
None
```

Вообще, когда мне нужно получать значение по ключу и ключ по значению, я завожу два словаря.

Comment: Можно инвертировать словарь `inv_d = {value: key for key, value in d.items()}` и еще раз вывести значение по ключу. Но может есть еще способ? Что-то можно подставить в print в моем случае?

Comment: Функцию get_key, например. Или используя инвертированный словарь: `for k in inv_d: print(inv_d[k])`. Тут у нас в `k` будет значение оригинального словаря и соответственно, мы будем получать и выводить ключи по значениям

Answer (score 4):

> Т.е. для строки 'a3a2c' ожидаемый вывод '113' и 'cb'

Если есть словарь `d` и коллекция ключей `keys`, то чтобы получить соответствующие значения, используя `default` значения для отсутствующих ключей:

```
def get_values(d, keys, default=None):
    return (d.get(k, default) for k in keys)
```

Пример:

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
s = 'a3a2c'
print(''.join(get_values(d, s, ''))) # -> 113
inv_d = dict(zip(d.values(), d.keys()))
print(''.join(get_values(inv_d, s, ''))) # -> cb
```

Если хочется сразу отфильтровать отсутствующие ключи:

```
def get_existing_values(d, keys):
    return filter(None, map(d.get, keys))
```

Пример:

```
>>> ''.join(get_existing_values(inv_d, s))
'cb'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in a:
    print ("%s -> %s" % (key, a[key])) #python3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d=dict(a='1',b='2',c='3') # первый словарь


print(d)    

stroka = 'a3a2c'
print('stroka=',stroka)


for m in stroka:                #поиск элементов из stroka в ключах d
    if m in d.keys():                   #вывод значений этих лючей
        print('буква ', m, 'из строки "stroka" является ключом значения ', d[m]) 

s=[]
for i in d.keys():      #второй
    s.append((d[i],i))  #словарь
b=dict(s)               #является обратным для первого
                        #значения являются ключами, а ключи значениями

stroka_=stroka


for i in stroka_:               #поиск элементов из stroka в значениях d 
    if i in b.keys():               #вывод ключей этих значений
        print('цифра ', i, 'из строки "stroka" является значением ключа', b[i])
```

Но задача была бы чуть интересней, если бы представление значений словаря было не строчным, а целочисленным.

Answer (score 1):

Для словаря {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} 
(значения словаря являются элементами типа int)

```
d=dict(a=1,b=2,c=3) # первый словарь


print(d)    

stroka = 'a3a2c'
print('stroka=',stroka)


for m in stroka:                #поиск элементов из stroka в ключах d
    if m in d.keys():                   #вывод значений этих лючей
        print('буква ', m, 'из строки "stroka" является ключом значения ', d[m]) 

s=[]
for i in d.keys():      #второй
    s.append((d[i],i))  #словарь
b=dict(s)               #является обратным для первого
                        #значения являются ключами, а ключи значениями

stroka_=stroka  #stroka_ = 'a3a2c'


            #поиск элементов из stroka в значениях d 
                    #вывод ключей этих значений


v=','.join(str(b.keys()))
#v=d,i,c,t,_,k,e,y,s,(,[,1,,, ,2,,, ,3,],)

s_=[]
for i in v:
    try:                            
        s_.append(int(i)) 
    except ValueError as e:
        continue

# s_= [1, 2, 3]

i=0
while i < len(s_):
    s_[i]=str(s_[i])
    i+=1
# s_= ['1', '2', '3']



 #поиск элементов из stroka в значениях d 
                    #вывод ключей этих значений


for i in stroka_:    #stroka_ = 'a3a2c'
    if i in s_:         # s_= ['1', '2', '3']
        print('значение', stroka_[stroka_.index(i)], 'из строки "stroka" является значением ключа', b[int(i)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict = {'george': 16, 'amber': 19}
print mydict.keys()[mydict.values().index(16)]  # Prints george
```

Or in Python 3.x:

```
mydict = {'george': 16, 'amber': 19}
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index(16)])
```

Source - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять готовую реализацию двустороннего словаря [bidict](https://pypi.org/project/bidict/) (`pip install bidict`).

Пример на вашем коде:

```
from bidict import bidict

d = bidict({'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'})
stroka = 'a3a2c'

for i in stroka:
    if i in d.keys():
        print(d[i], end='')

print()

for j in stroka:
    if j in d.values():
        print(d.inverse[j], end='')

print()
```

Вывод:

```
113
cb
```

Answer (score 0):

решил вашу проблему немного по-другому.

просто превратите ключи словаря в `tuple`  методом `list()` и сохраните его в новой переменной, затем вызовите значения ключа и сохраните его в переменной, и в конце уже можно

```
print(переменная_1[индекс ключа которую вы сохранили], переменная_2[индекс ключ]
```

Comment: сорри превратите в список методом list()

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, есть словарь с некоторыми одинаковыми значениями и нужно достать ключи по какому-то значению, например, три:

```
xxx = {"Джон":"три","Джек":"пять","Константин":"сорок","Вася":"три"}    

imena_x = [] #сюда будут поступать ключи от значений

for key,value in xxx.items(): # перебирает ключи и значения в словаре
    if 'три' in value:      # если находит значение в словаре "три"
        imena_x.append(key) # добавляет ключ этого значения в список
```